# insmod: ERROR: Could not insert module : No such device

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to implement character device driver in C at Linux.
My code is as follows:

```
#include<linux/device.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/err.h>
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#define SUCCESS 0
#define DEVICE_NAME "chardev"
#define BUF_LEN 80

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int Major;
static char msg[BUF_LEN]={0};
static short s_o_msg;
static int Device_Open = 0;
static struct class* chardevClass = NULL;
static struct device* chardevDevice = NULL;
static char *msg_Ptr;

static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);



static struct file_operations fops = {
        .read = device_read,
        .write = device_write,
        .open = device_open,
        .release = device_release
};

static int __init chardev_init(void){
    Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);

    if (Major < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Registering char device failed with %d\n", Major);
        return Major;
    }

    chardevDevice = device_create(chardevClass, NULL, MKDEV(Major,0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(chardevDevice)) {
        class_destroy(chardevClass);
        unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
        printk(KERN_ALERT
        "Failed to create the device\n");
        return PTR_ERR(chardevDevice);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "I was assigned major number %d. To talk to\n", Major);
    printk(KERN_INFO "the driver, create a dev file with\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "'mknod /dev/%s c %d 0'.\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Try various minor numbers. Try to cat and echo to\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "the device file.\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Remove the device file and module when done.\n");

    return SUCCESS;
}

static void __exit chardev_exit(void){
    device_destroy(chardevClass, MKDEV(Major, 0));
    class_unregister(chardevClass);
    class_destroy(chardevClass);
    unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye!\n");
}

static int device_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    static int counter = 0;

    if (Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;

    Device_Open++;
    sprintf(msg, "I already told you %d times Hello world!\n", counter++);
    msg_Ptr = msg;
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);

    return SUCCESS;
}

static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset){

    int bytes_read = 0;

    if (*msg_Ptr == 0)
        return 0;

    while (length && *msg_Ptr) {

        put_user(*(msg_Ptr++), buffer++);

        length--;
        bytes_read++;
    }

    return bytes_read;
}

static int device_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep)
{
    Device_Open--;

    module_put(THIS_MODULE);

    return 0;
}



static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset){
    sprintf(msg, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, length);
    s_o_msg = strlen(msg);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Received %zu characters from the user\n", length);
    return length;
}

module_init(chardev_init);
module_exit(chardev_exit);
```

then, I compile this with following command and to this moment everything looks just fine:

```
obj-m := memory.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

but when I tried to run this module with

```
sudo /sbin/insmod memory.ko
```

I get an error :

```
insmod: ERROR: Could not insert module : No such device
```

Could you explain me please what I'm doing wrong and what should I do to run this module properly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show the `make` output.

Comment: after run directrly insmod memory.ko i recived message: device not found

Comment: check my answer, you didn't created class using `class_create()` because of that `insmod` fails.

Comment: @heszek if any the ans listed below has helped you then upvote it. If you have found any other way to fix the issue then please add it as ans below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to create the class( `class_create`) before `device_create()` because if you see

```
root@achal:/sys/class# ls
.. there are so many different class..
```

your `device` also should be in `one class` that's why create one class using  `class_create();`

Add below line in your code.

```
chardevClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "overflow");

    chardevDevice = device_create(chardevClass, NULL, MKDEV(Major,0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
```

**root** mode is required for `inserting` a module, Sequence for `compiling`, `inserting` and running a module are :
First do `make`

```
root@root:~/s_flow# make
```

then do `insmod` & analyse `dmesg` output

```
 root@root:~/s_flow# insmod memory.ko
    root@root:~/s_flow# dmesg
    ..
    .. check here whether  __init chardev_init() is invoked or not
```

or you can check `modinfo` also

```
root@root:~/s_flow# modifno memory.ko
```

I hope it helps.